# How to compare two lists with different name reference but with same actual data

Tags: java, string, list, selenium, object

I have 2 lists which got the same content but with different name reference.

I have a table which I download with a button 'Export' which download a CSV file to my local file system and I am getting table using selenium I have tried to convert those lists into 'Collections' but that did not do the trick.

This is how my CSV list looks like:

```
AuditCsvRow{dateStr='"2019-04-14 11:48"', userStr='"admin"', entityStr='"Users"', actionStr='"Login"', nameStr='"admin"', descriptionStr='"User login successful: admin"', clientIpStr='"192.168.51.35"'}
```

This is the list downloaded using selenium:

```
AuditRow{dateStr='2019-04-14 11:48', userStr='admin', entityStr='Users', actionStr='Login', nameStr='admin', descriptionStr='User login successful: admin', clientIpStr='192.168.51.35', clientIpTxt='192.168.51.35'}
```

```
List<AuditRow> uiRowList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<AuditCsvRow>CSVrows = readAuditLogFromCSV(CSV_FILE_PATH);
        uiRowList = auditPage.getAudittable();
 Collection listOne = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(CSVrows));
        Collection listTwo = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(uiRowList));

        listOne.equals(listTwo);
```

```
private List<AuditRow> readAuditLogFromCSV(String fileName) throws IOException {
        List<AuditRow> rowsList = new ArrayList<>();
        Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);

        try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)){
            String line = br.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                String[] attributes = line.split(",");
                AuditRow auditCsvRow = auditPage.createCsvRow(attributes);
                rowsList.add(auditCsvRow);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
        return rowsList;
    }
```

Comment: Change your `readAuditLogFromCSV` method to load the data into `AuditRow` objects and get rid of the duplicate class `AuditCsvRow` Also get rid of the lines `Collection listOne = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(CSVrows));
        Collection listTwo = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(uiRowList));` as they do nothing useful, `uiRowList` and `CSVRows` are already lists.

Comment: The lists do not contain the same content. The first list includes double quotes which the second list does not. Apparently, your CSV reading method for the first should have included a quote character.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBolwidt I did use your suggestion but now I am facing a problem where my item in the list is double quoted for some reason, this is how I parse the CSV file into a list (EDITED MY QUESTION AT THE END).

Comment: @RealSkeptic - How would you handle the double quoted ? I have added to my question the method which I am using to parse CSV lines into a list.

Comment: I would use a CSV parser, there are common libraries available. CSV is not just splitting by commas. There are quoting and escaping that need to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Erwin Bolwidt is very good, it helps you to reduce duplicated code. However, I would like to share my trick to compare objects like that.

Basically, I would parse them into Json and compare the strings

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
boolean isTheSameData = gson.toJson(CSVrows).equals(gson.toJson(uiRowList));
```